# Manipulate JSON with Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I have the following problem. I have a Writer class which writes me all objects I create into a JSON file via Gson. The output looks like that:

```
    {
  "eventID": 1,
  "title": "one",
  "timeCreated": "Sep 23, 2007, 10:10:00 AM",
  "timeModified": "Sep 23, 2007, 10:10:00 AM",
  "timeStart": "Nov 11, 2999, 11:11:00 AM",
  "timeEnd": "Nov 11, 3999, 11:11:00 AM",
  "alarmOn": true,
  "content": ""
}
```

eventID is a serialized integer created with AtomicInteger each time a new obj get created.

I want to manipulate those object e.g., set a new title.
So in the first step I tried to get the JSON back into java via fromJson

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type myDataType = new TypeToken<Collection<Event>>() {
}.getType();
Collection<Event> myData = gson.fromJson("awesome.json", myDataType);
for (Event e : myData) {
    System.out.println("value= " + e.getTitle());
}
```

However, this leads to an error

> Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

How do I properly read my json back to my java class, apply some changes and write it after back again to json?

Comment: Can you print the contents of `awesome.json` you mention in the code.

Comment: The contents of the string `"awesome.json"` **is** `awesome.json`. The OP is confused with this overload: https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class- -- it **only** accepts JSONs as strings, and yeah `awesome.json` **it not** a valid JSON, it looks like a filename, resource name, whatever, but not a JSON at all. Read the contents of the file into a string, or better open a `java.io.InputStream`, wrap it in `java.io.Reader` and pass to the `fromJson` method overload.

Answer (score -1):

Let's look at the error code

> Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

So, it seems that the library is expecting a `json array`, but you give it a String instead.

It most probably has to do with this like `new TypeToken<Collection<Event>>()` you are saying that your type is a `collection` of events, not a single event.

Try changing it to `TypeToken<Event>` and see if this works.